# List those nodes which are not referenced through a reference field in other nodes?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have content type which has a node reference field of the same content type.

I want to list only those nodes which are not referenced through this node reference field in any other node.

Is it possible with views?

Comment: I think you'l have to write your own query or use hook_views_query_alter to alter your views query. I don't think this is possible out of the box